# Servlet Mapping and deploying in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I am developing a simple servlet based web application. I am not using any IDE. Following are the steps that i have followed.

1. Folder Structure :

   - MyAPP -> Contains WEB-INF folder and index.html
   - WEB-INF contains 2 folders and web.xml.
   - Path to loginServlet.java : MyAPP\WEB-INF\classes\servletclass\loginServlet.java
   - WEB_INF contains lib folder which conatins servlet-api.jar
2. index.html contains a form and the action attribute of the form contains "login" as value.
3. MyAPP\WEB-INF\web.xml looks like below :

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>   
   <servlet>
           <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>servletclass.loginServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>


   <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>



   <session-config>
           <session-timeout>
                   30
           </session-timeout>
   </session-config>

   </web-app>
   ```
4. Compiled the loginServlet.java using command prompt. It created a loginServlet.class file.
5. Now built a war file using command prompt and deployed it on Tomcat server.
6. Now when i run the application, it succesfully loads index.html. But as soon as click on Submit button in the form it shows the following error:

   ```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: servletclass/loginServlet (wrong name: loginServlet)
   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2260)
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:803)
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:456)
   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1452)
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   ```

Comment: Do you have a package declaration in your servlet class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621572/cant-run-my-servlet-from-tomcat-server-even-though-the-classes-are-in-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan is right, do you have the following declaration in your Java file?

```
package servletclass;
```